# Not able to deserialize JSON array with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, deserialization

I'm overlooking something that's probably basic. Trying to deserialize a JSON file but I'm getting the error.

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RosterAppsPayrollToADP.Models.PayPeriodData]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

I think I have it setup okay but obviously I'm missing something and I'm not seeing it.

Starting up a new C# console app that will eventually call a 3rd party API but for now I'm trying to mimic what the JSON response should be.

JSON file

```
{
  "PayPeriodData": [
    {
      "PayrollID": "123",
      "PayRoleGroupName": "Biweekly",
      "PayPeriodStart": "2020-11-07",
      "PayPeriodEnd": "2020-11-20",
      "IsFrozen": "true",
      "FrozenOn": "2020-11-25T18:03:12",
      "CreatedOn": "2020-11-25T18:03:12",
      "ProcessedOn": "2020-11-25T18:03:12"
    },
    {
      "PayrollID": "124",
      "PayRoleGroupName": "Weekly",
      "PayPeriodStart": "2020-11-14",
      "PayPeriodEnd": "2020-11-20",
      "IsFrozen": "true",
      "FrozenOn": "2020-11-25T18:03:12",
      "CreatedOn": "2020-11-25T18:03:12",
      "ProcessedOn": "2020-11-25T18:03:12"
    }
  ]
}
```

Model Class

```
public class PayPeriodRequest
{
    public List<PayPeriod> PayPeriodData { get; set; } 
           
}

public class PayPeriod 
{
    public string PayrollID { get; set; }
    public string PayRoleGroupName { get; set; }
    public string PayPeriodStart { get; set; }
    public string PayPeriodEnd { get; set; }
    public string IsFrozen { get; set; }
    public string FrozenOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string ProcessedOn { get; set; }
}
```

C# Code

```
List<PayPeriodRequest> listPayPeriodData = _dataManager.GetPayPeriodData();
```

Data Manager

```
public List<PayPeriodRequest> GetPayPeriodData()
            {
                _log.LogInformation("Getting pay period data.");
    
    
                List<PayPeriodRequest> listPayPeriodData = new List<PayPeriodRequest>();
                try
                {
                    string jsonData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\PayPeriodDataSample.json");
    
                    listPayPeriodData  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PayPeriodRequest>>(jsonData);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _log.LogError("Error getting pay period data. {0} | {1} | {2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException);
                }
                
                return listPayPeriodData;
            }
```

Comment: You have a json object with a property that is an array. The object itself is not an array. You need to parse it as an object and reference PayPeriodData inside it.

Comment: As per previous comment, you need to deserialize into a `PayPeriodRequest`, not `List<PayPeriodRequest>`

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=lPXRJhigrVSlcwwWVncm

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data contains a single `PayPeriodRequest` which cannot be serialized to a `List<PayPeriodRequest>`:

```
PayPeriodRequest payPeriodRequest = null;
try
{
    string jsonData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\PayPeriodDataSample.json");

    payPeriodRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayPeriodRequest>(jsonData);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error getting pay period data. {0} | {1} | {2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException);
}
```

Once you have deserialized the `PayPeriodRequest`, you can simply use its `PayPeriodData` property to get the `List<PayPeriod>`.